# customize 502 bad gateway error for ReactJS App

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I would like to customize the 502 bad gateway error, shown when the React JS App  is not available (started using `yarn start`).

How to customize the landing page for common HTTP errors

Comment: I assume you want to do this for your production build as well?

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: yes @squillman we want to do for production build as well

Comment: yes @Costa we use react router

Comment: Ok, then I'm also going to assume that your production deployment will run on a production HTTP server and as such will not be launched with `yart start` such as your development build is.  If that be the case then you should investigate what it takes to do custom errors with whatever production HTTP server you plan to use (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc).  If, on the other hand, all you want is for your React app to throw a custom error when your API is unreachable then use a `<Redirect>` from react-router to your own custom error page.  It would get called after an error contacting your API.

Comment: for the time being we intend to run with yarn start in production as well